# Как открыть браузер через сервис Windows на Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, webbrowser, сервисы

Возникла проблема c открытием браузера средствами Python 3.x.

```
import webbrowser

url = 'https://ru.stackoverflow.com/'
browser_path = "C:/Users/Андрей/AppData/Local/Yandex/YandexBrowser/Application/browser.exe %s"

webbrowser.get(browser_path).open(url)
```

При запуске из консоли, код работает замечательно и все открывает, однако, если попробовать запустить его как сервис Windows, браузер перестает открываться. (В диспетчере задач видно, что создается один или несколько процессов браузера в фоновом режиме). Смена браузера не помогла.

Запуск в виде сервиса нужен, т.к. скрипт должен будет слушать трафик, запускаясь одновременно с системой.

Вот код, который не работает:

```
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import servicemanager
import socket
import webbrowser


class AppServerSvc (win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "TestService"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Test Service"

    def __init__(self,args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self,args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None,0,0,None)
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                              servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
                              (self._svc_name_,''))
        self.main()

    def main(self):
        url = 'https://ru.stackoverflow.com/'
        browser_path = "C://Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s"

        webbrowser.get(browser_path).open(url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AppServerSvc)
```

**Буду крайне рад, если кто-то сможет помочь! Спасибо!**

P.S.
Настройка сервиса в окне "Вход в систему", тоже не принесла результатов, ни под системной учетной записью с доступом к рабочему столу, ни под учетной записью пользователя.

Comment: У сервисов свои отдельные рабочие столы, они не имеют доступа к рабочему столу текущего пользователя (к тому же текущего пользователя вообще может не быть, если ещё не совершён вход). Хотите отобразить браузер пользователю — добавляйте этому пользователю автозагрузку вместо использования сервиса

Comment: @andreymal там есть галочка "разрешить взаимодействие с раб столом" тогда при появлении окна рабочий стол переключается через уведомление